# How to use a variable as js code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to add the data into below function using jQuery (or highcharts). The question is how to embed the data into the javascript code without using eval since I will have to write all the code as string?

```
function pie(data)
{
  $(function () {
    $('#renderingdiv').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [**data**]
    });
});
};
```

**data** looks like:

```
{\
            type: 'pie',\
            name: 'Statuses',\
            data: [\
                [WSCH,   377]\
        ,\
                [WMATL,   4]\
        ,\
                [WAPPR,   349]\
        ,\
                [NCOMP,   3]\
        ,\
                [INPRG,   56]\
        ,\
                [COMP,   18]\
        ,\
                [CLOSE,   697]\
        ,\
                [APPR,   420]\
        \
            ]\
        }
```

Any idea please?

Comment: you have any framework behind it ?

Comment: Any reason on why you dont want to use eval() ? just asking out of curiosity

Comment: Is `data` supposed to be a string literal? Then use `JSON.parse` instead of `eval`. If not, what are all those backslashes doing there? And how did you got them there in the first place? Remove them and you could just use the markup as a JS object literal.

Comment: @john: yes, special framework. The question, in general, how to embed a variable in the code without using eval?

Comment: @Raghu: eval is not preferable as data may contain some characters plus it will require lot of coding to break lines with \.

Comment: @Bergi: backslashes are used to construct the string in order to be passed as argument to the function pie. not using json format as other libraries don't support it. regardless of how we got the string, is there a way to add it to the js code?

Comment: take a look if your framework can do something like groovy can, deliver the object encoded as javascript

Comment: Well, the thing is that the jscode (pie) is static in a file but data is passed to jsp which should pass the variable to the static function.... Well, eventually eval can be used but the code will look creepy. I bet there is another way.. isn;t it ? In addition, eval will require escaping of the text. I just don't like that function!

Comment: @ Bergi: how can I use the markup as a JS object literal? can you please explain as I didn't understand what you mean?

Comment: @user2735719: Simply don't construct it as a string! Pass it as an object literal to the `pie` function. Please [show us](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18625157/edit) your framework code that constructs the data, and tag your question with the framework name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick and dirty function converts your data to valid JSON and returns an object.

```
function parseData(data) {    
    data = data
        // remove \+line endings
        .replace(/\[\n\r]+/g, '') 
        // insert double quotes for keys
        .replace(/([\[{,])\s*(\w+)([,:])/g, '$1"$2"$3') 
        // replace values single quotes with double
        .replace(/(:)\s*'(\w+)\s*'/g, '$1"$2"'); 
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

Of course you should improve this to handle corner cases.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qq98D/2/ (result in console output)

But this is just a workaround. The real solution is to change the server output to return valid JSON.

**Result** (JSON encoded):

> {"type":"pie","name":"Statuses","data":[["WSCH",377],["WMATL",4],["WAPPR",349],["NCOMP",3],["INPRG",56],["COMP",18],["CLOSE",697],["APPR",420]]}

Comment: Yes but my issue is not with converting to JSON. I need the other format of data as it was shown above. I want a mechanism of adding the data string variable (which may include itself some js code) into the function as if it is part of the pie function code